# Text based (console) UI for Python

Tags: python, console

I'd like to code a small application for the console (Linux Server) and I am looking for a package to create a UserInterface to display and enter some data.

Is there such a package?

Regards Steff

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to embed a console in your user interface, then I suggest you can use [PyQt Console](https://pypi.org/project/pyqtconsole/). You will need to design your user interface using PyQt and embed the console in it.

Comment: No I am looking for a old-schol 'DOS' UserInterface for the server (like htop). I don't like to write to webui for interaction.